# Regex to remove and replace characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following

```
<option value="Abercrombie">Abercrombie</option>
```

My file has about 2000 rows in it each row has a different location, I'm trying to understand regex but unfortunately nothing I learn will go in and I'm unsure if this is possible.

What I want to do is run a regex which will strip the above HTML which will leave the following

```
Abercrombie
```

I then want to prefix a particular number to the front so the result would be for example

```
2,Abercrombie
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Capture groups. But no. Because this is HTML, regex is not the way to go. An XML / HTML parser is. Regex stands for "regular expressions", and HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: @milliesmith I've just done a Google search on html parsers I get a few results but I can find how to manipulate html I.e what I'm trying to do above or even where to start with such a task I'm really hoping I haven't got to do this manually

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @MillieSmith sorry I should of mentioned this in the question I'm using c#

Comment: Do not answer in a comment, please tag the language in the question :)

Comment: It is possible but if you have a file, why not simply use a text editor to replace? A lot of text editors support regexes for find and replace.

Comment: @m0skit0 yeah text-editor is fine if the values are all the same, I have 2980 rows in my txt file each row has a different value i.e location so I could do find and replace  <option value=" and then to </option> which would remove the vast majority of it, but I will be left with AbercrombieAbercrombie I will then need to go through and remove the duplicate name leaving Abercrombie and then prefix a number to it

Comment: Ok but the regexes differ, specially the syntaxes of replace groups

Comment: @ScottAtkinson was the answer entirely what you wanted? I was going to edit it to include the entire html text (stripping out options and leaving the values in their place) because I thought I had misread the question.

Comment: @MillieSmith absolutely spot on, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression since HTML is not a regular language. You can use Linq's XML parser. If you want to process the entire file, you can replace the elements inline:

```
int myNumber  = 2;
var html      = @"<html><body><option value=""Abercrombie"">Abercrombie</option><div><option value=""Forever21"">Forever21</option></div></body></html>";            
var doc       = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(html));

var options = doc.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name == "option").ToList();
foreach (var element in options)
{
    element.ReplaceWith(string.Format("{0},{1}", myNumber, element.Value));
}

var result = doc.ToString();
```

This gives:

```html
<html>
    <body>2,Abercrombie<div>2,Forever21</div></body>
</html>
```

If you just want to grab the text for a specific tag, you can use the following:

```
int myNumber  = 2;
var html      = @"<option value=""Abercrombie"">Abercrombie</option>";            
var doc       = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(html));
var element   = doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "option");
var attribute = element.Attribute("value").Value;
var result    = string.Format("{0},{1}", myNumber, attribute);

//result == "2,Abercrombie"
```